# UIView transition animation memory leak

Tags: swift, uiview, memory-leaks

Please help me fix a memory leak I don't understand.  I have a custom UIButton subclass that transitions between two images.

```
class SettingsButton: OMGButton {

var settingsButtonTimer: Timer?

enum SettingsButtonImage: String {
    case Gears
    case Person = "Add Person"
}

var transitioning: Bool = false

var currentButtonImage: SettingsButtonImage = .Gears {
    didSet {
        self.handleImageChange()
    }
}

override func configure() {
    super.configure()
    self.settingsButtonTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 15, target: self, selector: #selector(changeImage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func changeImage() {
    if self.currentButtonImage == .Gears {
        self.currentButtonImage = .Person
    } else {
        self.currentButtonImage = .Gears
    }
}

func handleImageChange() {
    if !self.transitioning {
        UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 1.5, options: [.beginFromCurrentState, .transitionCrossDissolve], animations: { [unowned self] in
            self.transitioning = true

            // setImage is leaking memory on each transition

            self.setImage(UIImage(named: self.currentButtonImage.rawValue), for: .normal)

        }, completion: { _ in
            self.transitioning = false
        })
    }
}
```

}

The handleImageChange() method is leaking memory - specifically it shows it's leaking on the line where I set the image:

```
self.setImage(UIImage(named: self.currentButtonImage.rawValue), for: .normal)
```

Please help me understand why that is leaking memory.  Thank you!